# Overlapping video views in Android

Tags: android

I want to know if it is possible to get overlapping videoviews, like for ex. we get in Skype, for android applications. 
Can I get the basic Logic on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, except perhaps on Android 4.0+ with the use of `TextureView` and `MediaPlayer` instead of `VideoView` (which uses `SurfaceView` in its implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the information...
Can you tell me if it is possible to implement a picture on picture at least then?

Comment: @user1257050: You can overlap two `ImageView` widgets, if that is what you mean.